# Are there any studies comparing the ecological footprint of an e-ink tablet with traditional pen and paper?

Tags: environmental-impact, ecological-footprint, alternatives

I am a graduate student in physics and I was considering getting a paper tablet like the [reMarkable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReMarkable) or the [Sony DPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Digital_Paper_DPTS1) to replace the notebooks where I do calculations and take notes. But I was wondering if there are any studies comparing the ecological impact of these kind of tablets with the one of just buying paper notebooks and pens.

I am wondering if it evens out after enough time and usage or the tablets are still way off for any normal user.

Comment: There are 2 related questions asked here: [How do word processing on a laptop and writing with pen and paper stack up sustainability-wise?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3210/99) and [Reading on paper vs. screen](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/487/99). Your question is different because of the writing on screen, but my guess is that the total impact is not that different from an ebook used for reading.